# Java Access Modifier Best Practice

Tags: java, variables, methods, access-modifiers

This may seem a basic question, but I'd like to get this right.

I have a Class 'AWorld'. Within that class, I have a method that draws a border, depending on the map size set by the user.

If the variable 'mapSize' is private, but I want to access it's value from within the same class, is it more appropriate to reference it directly, or use a getter method.

The code below should explain what I'm wanting to know.

```
package javaFX;

public class AWorld {
    //initialized later
    AWorld newWorld;

    private int mapSize = 20;

    public int getMapSize()
    {
        return mapSize;
    }

    public void someMethod()
    {
        int var = newWorld.mapSize; //Do I reference 'mapSize' using this...
    }
    // Or...

    public void someOtherMethod()
    {
        int var = newWorld.getMapSize(); //Or this?
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {}

}
```

Comment: I think the bigger issue here is why does the class `AWorld` contain an instance of `AWorld`? You have created an infinite loop. Every time you create an `AWorld` the construction creates a new `AWorld` and down you go till out of memory.

Comment: @JohnB it's explained in the text in the question. Looks like a wrapper. Probably it should be injected rather than created internally.

Comment: Disregard the newWorld instance, I threw this together as example code to ask the question, as the class I'm using is considerably longer.

Comment: To answer your question, general practice would be to use field as `mapSize` or `this.mapSize` if the class if `final`. If it is not final and there is a chance to overload the value, you MIGHT consider `getMapSize` but you have added complexity that you probably don't need.

Comment: @JohnB you're getting it wrong. OP wants to know how to make use of `newWorld#mapSize` inside the code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza he cannot directly access "newWorld.mapsize", since it is private field. Do it through getter.

Comment: @kyla it's `AWorld newWorld` and the class is `AWorld`. It can access to the private field directly because it's the same class.

Comment: @kyla you are wrong. The Class is the same so it can access the variable.

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi oh right, I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of those is ok since you're getting a primitive field. If the `get` method does another operation before returning the data e.g. performing a math operation on the value, then it would be better to use it rather than calling the field directly. This is specially meant when using proxy/decorator pattern on your classes.

Here's an example of the second statement from above:

```
//base class to be decorated
abstract class Foo {
    private int x;
    protected Foo foo;
    public int getX() { return this.x; }
    public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
    public Foo getFoo() { return this.foo; }

    //method to prove the difference between using getter and simple value
    public final void printInternalX() {
        if (foo != null) {
            System.out.println(foo.x);
            System.out.println(foo.getX());
        }
    }
}

//specific class implementation to be decorated
class Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return super.getX() * 10;
    }
}

//decorator
class Baz extends Foo {
    public Baz(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo1 = new Bar();
        foo1.setX(10);
        Foo foo2 = new Bar(foo1);
        //here you see the difference
        foo2.printInternalX();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
10
100
```

Comment: do u mean newWorld.mapSize == mapSize ?

Comment: @Yazan I never meant that.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I agree with you. It would help if you could provide a concrete example in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You better dereference it directly.

The point of the private modifier is not to expose internal implementation to other classes. These other classes will use the getter method to get the value of the private property.

In your own class, there is no point on using the getter. Worse, someone may have overridden that method in a class that extends your class, and the getter may perform something that you do not expect

Comment: This is almost true unless you or another framework use proxy classes rather than your classes e.g. Hibernate. In this case, Hiberante docs recommend to use getters rather than direct fields since it may not have been retrieved yet due to it needs to do an internal database call before filling the value of the field.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I assumed that getters/direct access do exactly the same thing. If the aren't, there is no point asking if you should use one or the other, you must use the one that does the job that you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, if you are referencing a field of the current instance the general rule is to access the field directly with `mapSize` or `this.mapSize`.

If you are referencing a value from a different instance (be it of the same class or a different class, I would use the getter method). I believe this would lead to simpler refactoring. It also maintains the contract that any other instance gets the field value via the getter which allows for additional functionality in the getter.

Comment: This approach is pro-active. @Luigi's answer is reactive. In this case, I like the latter one.